# Load local.env.js in Angular-fullstack

Tags: angularjs, express, environment-variables

I've set some environment variables in the file local.env.js, and I can see in the Gruntfile that local.env.js is accessed and its content pushed into localConfig, but I can't seem to access them at `process.env.MY_ENV_VAR`

What am I missing? Is there another configuration or require statement I should be executing?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting actual environment variables on the shell you are executing grunt from?

Example using your variable name, place the following line in .bash_profile (if you run bash):

```
export MY_ENV_VAR="string value"
```

The native nodejs process picks up these environment variables and passes them to grunt.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I can do that, but I was expecting grunt to do this for me - I think from the configuration in the Gruntfile, it should be doing so.  The Gruntfile is spit out by yeoman, and I was wondering if the scaffolding from generator-angular-fullstack was leaving something unplugged, and whether others were having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem. My issue was with grunt. I stopped the grunt serve process, made the change, and then ran grunt serve in the console. Grunt did not update the assignment of the environmental variable.

Here is an example of using the variable.

```
module.exports = {
  // MongoDB connection options
  mongo: {
    uri: process.env.DB_DEV_URI
  },

  seedDB: true
};

//DB_DEV_URI is assigned in the local.env.js file
```